# NullReferenceException with an Array in C# 

Tags: c#, arrays, nullreferenceexception

I want to create an array containing all the Pushpin objects I am dealing with. While trying to populate the Array, I am getting a NullReferenceException Unhandled error thrown. I have read as much documentation as I can find and cannot work out what is going on.

I have tried at least the following:

```
Pushpin[] arrayPushpins;
int i = 0;
foreach (Result result in arrayResults)
                {
                    Pushpin pin;
                    pin = new Pushpin();
                    pin.Location = d;
                    myMap.Children.Add(pin);
                    arrayPushpins[i] = new Pushpin();
                    arrayPushpins.SetValue(pin, i);;
                    i++;
                }
```

AND...

```
Pushpin[] arrayPushpins;
int i = 0;
foreach (Result result in arrayResults)
                {
                    Pushpin pin;
                    pin = new Pushpin();
                    pin.Location = d;
                    myMap.Children.Add(pin);
                    arrayPushpins[i] = new Pushpin();
                    arrayPushpins[i] = pin;
                    i++;
                 }
```

And nothing seems to work... I get the NullReference error every time. 
Any ideas?
Many thanks!
Will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you don't initialize your array:

```
Pushpin[] arrayPushpins = new Pushpin[10]; // Creates array with 10 items
```

You might consider using `IEnumerable<Pushpin>` if you don't know the number of items in advance, e.g:

```
IEnumerable<Pushpin> pushpins = new List<Pushpin>
```

Comment: Why not use a `IEnumerable` Collection instead?

Comment: initialising the array fixed. Strange, I thought I had tried that too, but potentially not in combination with using the SetValue method. Thanks, Amittai. I will also try using a Collection, as I think you are all right - it will be better in this case as the number of pins can vary.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize the array

```
 Pushpin[] arrayPushpins = new Pushpin[/*number goes here*/];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (Result result in arrayResults)
                    {
                        Pushpin pin;
                        pin = new Pushpin();
                        pin.Location = d;
                        myMap.Children.Add(pin);
                        arrayPushpins[i] = new Pushpin();
                        arrayPushpins.SetValue(pin, i);;
                        i++;
                    }
```

Edited to add:  I'd avoid using a raw array, and go with something like a `List<Pushpin>` instead

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a list instead of an array. That way, you won't have to know in advance how many elements will you have in your list.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the array is only declared, not initialized. You need to initialize it with the new keyword.

```
Pushpin [] arrayPushpins= new Pushpin[50];
```

As the other answers recommend, you can use lists or collections.